# TST. holomorphic $f$ is constant,

Tags: complex-analysis

> We have $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C} $ open and connected.
>
> $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ and  $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.
>
> $f(\Omega)$ is contained in a straight line passing through origin.
>
> Show that $f$ is constant.

**My attempt:** I know that for $f=u+iv$ where  $u,v : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, if $$\partial_xu(x,y) = \partial_yu(x,y)=0 $$ then $u$ is constant. So I need to get these conditions for both $u$ and $v$ to show $f$ is constant

But how do I use  $f(\Omega)$ is contained in a straight line passing through origin?

EDIT : I am not supposed to use Open mapping theorem. As its not covered. I know using it would give me solution much easily.

Comment: @mrf looks like they have the right answer. I just wanted to say that this might also be relevant as well (but probably not) https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Analytic_Function_are_Isolated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(z) = e^{i\omega t}f(z)$, where $\omega$ is chosen so that $g$ is real-valued. (This is just a little make-up, to simplify the computations.)

Write $g = u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued. Then $v=0$, and Cauchy-Riemann gives $u'_x = v'_y = 0$ and $u'_y = -v'_x = 0$, so $u$ is constant. Consequently $g$, and thus $f$ is constant as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint- Open Mapping Theorem.$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: The OP writes "I am not supposed to use Open mapping theorem. As its not covered. I know using it would give me solution much easily."

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to use the open mapping theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Namely, since the domain of $f$ is open, we should have that either:

- $f$ is constant
- the image of $f$ is open

However, there are no open subsets of the straight line passing through the origin. Hence the image of $f$ must be a point, and therefore $f$ must be constant.

Comment: The OP writes "I am not supposed to use Open mapping theorem. As its not covered. I know using it would give me solution much easily."

Comment: @mrf Thank you for your concern. The OP edited their post to say that after the two answers mentioning the open mapping theorem was given. However, people looking at this question in the future might be allowed to use the open mapping theorem, and it is obviously the simplest way to approach the problem, so I don't see any reason to delete my post.

Comment: While in some sense the open mapping theorem is the "simplest" approach, it's a fairly big sledgehammer for a small problem. It takes quite a lot of effort to reach the open mapping theorem in a standard course on complex analysis, and someone who has reached that level of sophistication is unlikely to struggle with the problem at hand.

Comment: @mrf I respect your opinion, but it's easy for you to have when you walked in on the problem after everyone else had looked at it. OP did not mention in their original post that the open mapping theorem was not to be used. Moreover, saying that the results like the open mapping theorem are "sledgehammers" and shouldn't be used for simple problems is like saying one shouldn't use the inverse function theorem or the fundamental theorem of algebra except in the most convoluted cases -- utter nonsense. Moreover, the theorem is not much harder than Liouville's, i.e. not at all that sophisticated.